# How can I get the most balanced groups using matchit in R?

Tags: r, propensity-scores, matching

I have an imbalanced treatment group and a control group. I want to use **Matchit** in R to calculate **propensity scores** and get balanced groups.
However, there are **several parameters** I have to set in the Matchit package, for example, **method**, **ratio**, **distance**, and **caliper**. Each of these parameters has several options, for example, I can set method="nearest", "optimal", "genetic", distance="logit", "rpart", "nnet".
How can I choose from these options to get the **most balanced groups** (maybe indicated by the smallest Std. Mean Diff.)? There would be hundreds of combinations of these parameters.